# Prevent creating global variables from a function scope in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

In Groovy, when this function runs it will create a global variable `z`:

```
def defineGlobalVariable() {
    z = "hello"
}

defineGlobalVariable()
println(z)
// prints "hello"
```

I have a Groovy script with many functions that, without realizing, were written such that all their variables are defined as globals in this way. This is causing issues when I try to run some functions concurrently, because they alter the same global variable, thinking it's local to their scope.

I want to change all global variable definitions to local (e.g. changing `z = "hello"` to `def z = "hello"`). I can try finding and replacing them all with some regex, but I was wondering if maybe there's a way to just tell the groovy script to treat all variable definitions as local. Something like this:

```
def defineGlobalVariable() {
    z = "hello"
}

preventGlobalVariablesFromFunctions()
defineGlobalVariable()
println(z)
// fails - z doesn't exist in this scope
```

If such a thing doesn't exist, what is the safest way to find and replace all the global definitions?

**Edit for clarification:**
Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that will only prevent **creating** a global variable from a function scope, but will still allow **assigning** to it. Expanding on the previous example:

```
def shouldWork = "hi"

def assignToGlobalVariable() {
    shouldWork = "hello"
}

def defineGlobalVariable() {
    shouldFail = "hello"
}

preventGlobalVariablesFromFunctions()
assignToGlobalVariable()
println(shouldWork)
// prints "hello"
defineGlobalVariable()
println(shouldFail)
// fails - `shouldFail` doesn't exist in this scope
```

Comment: Your update to the question indicates that you want the assignment `shouldFail = "hello"` to work but you want `println(shouldFail)` to fail.  Is that intentional?

Comment: No, it is not. The hour was late and I botched the example, sorry… Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare function `void setProperty(String k,Object v)` which is used by groovy when you are trying to set "global" script variable.

```
void setProperty(String k,Object v){
    throw new Exception("not allowed to set global variable `$k` to value `$v`")
}

def defineGlobalVariable() {
    z = "hello"
}
defineGlobalVariable()
println(z)

//Exception thrown
//java.lang.Exception: not allowed to set global variable `z` to value `hello`
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution, thanks! However, there's one small issue: it prevent setting the global variable entirely, even it was already defined globally. I'm trying to find a solution that will only prevent creating the global variable from the function scope, but will still allow me to assign to it if it already exists.

Comment: no way to detect this. everything declared outside a function actually located inside the function `void run(){...}` during runtime - so, no difference between those cases.

Comment: I see… Can I use `setProperty` to somehow check if `k` already exists and only then throw the exception? I’m not very familiar with Groovy syntax, but for example in Python I can inspect the `globals()` dictionary. Is there something like that in Groovy? I’m also fine with a solution that will only work in a Jenkins pipeline if for some reason that gives more options…

Comment: script object has method `this.getBinding()` that returns all properties and variables. this should work for you: `this.getBinding().hasVariable("k")`

Comment: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html#getBinding()

Comment: That sounds promising, I’ll test it out :)